# Getting started with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I understand there is no proper answer to my question, but here it is:

What are the most common/important boost libraries that a programmer should know. I mean the must haves which lets you write "boost" on your resume'

Comment: It **depends** is the only sensible answer to be given here.  It depends on the problem domain you want to work in, the type of things you have to do, etc....

Comment: Whoa! I didn't expect so many down votes. I start learning C++ and somewhere I read something like "you gotta know Boost". So I go to boost.org and get familiar with what Boost is all about. Next question is where do I begin? What are the most commonly used or most generic ones? Isn't that a natural question?

Comment: Its certainly alright. I am very happy with the responses. Just wondering if asking a question like that is a bad idea. No flames.

Comment: As I said. I am pretty happy with the answer I got so far. My question is similar to a novice asking what all programming languages should I know to have a decent career : And the answer would be know at least 2/3 of C, C++, Java, python, perl, php, C#

Comment: I meant questions in general, not only this one. You've asked 6 questions and have only accepted one answer.

Comment: Ok. That is a bad habit. I have not picked up the habit to click the tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, the following are libraries I use all of the time:

1. `boost/smart_ptr`
2. `boost/bind`
3. `boost/io`
4. `boost/lambda`
5. `boost/regex`

Answer (score 5):

In addition the the libraries mentioned in Answer #1 other handy libraries include:

- Bimap
- Optional
- Random
- Tokenizer
- Format
- Foreach
- lexical cast
- Filesystem
- Date Time
- MPI  (clearly for parallel programming)